# use value instead of console logging

Tags: node.js, promise

```
            amber.send(avatarimage).then(sent => { 
                let image = sent.attachments.first().url;

            });
```

basically I am trying to use the `sent.attachments.first().url` instead of console logging it, I am not familiar with this and doing something like `amber.send(avatarimage).then(sent => let image = (sent.attachments.first().url));` does not work ofcourse, how do I get the value instead of logging it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. What do you mean by "get the value". The value is already there at that point. You might just be confused by Promises and asynchronous programming. And if you could provide some more context or code that would be helpful too, thanks.

Comment: @AlenGenzić basically I want to store `sent.attachments.first().url` in a variable but I do now know at what place and how I have to do that

Comment: It depends. If you want to use the `sent.attachments.first().url` you will have to use it inside the same scope in which it exists, which is inside the then callback.

Comment: @AlenGenzić I have edited the code, now I am trying to use `image` outside of the .then, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please add this explanation to the question? Thanks. You cannot use the image variable outside of the then because it does not exist before or after this scope. You will have to do all operations you want to do with the image variable immediately after `let image = sent.attachments.first().url;`

Comment: @Fes No, you can't use the `image` outside of the scope it is declared in. And of course you can't use it outside of the `then` callback, as that is what happens in the future - the code outside would execute immediately, when the value is not yet there. What do you want to do with the variable? Put all that code in the promise callback.

Comment: Take a look at async/await https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Promise, try async/await.

```
amber.send(avatarimage).then(sent => { 
    let image = sent.attachments.first().url;
});
```

is now

`const image = await amber.send(avatarimage);`

I have to warn you though, async/await is NOT a substitute for asynchronous programming, because it is STILL asynchronous programming with a very synchronous syntantic sugar sprinkled on it.

Or you could put the code inside where `image` is.